# Finding whether the convex cone from a vector list is null

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

Given a list of vectors, I want to find whether there exists a vector such that its dot product with those in the list is all (semi)positive, or at least above a certain small negative value.

Comment: What is the dimension of the ambient space? In principle, one can compute the convex hull of the points and check whether the origin is contained in the interior. _Mathematica_ provides `ConvexHullMesh`, but that works only in dimensions 2 and 3...

Comment: It's 7 dimensional. And the list is of 14 vectors. I was wondering whether Mathematica has some standard function for this sort of thing. I've searched the reference site for "convex cone" but haven't found anything.

Comment: Maybe you find this one interesting: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0305054893900803

Comment: After reading your post, I figured I could probably get the code to work by using a constrained NMinimize for the "Nearest" function, where you have one parameter for each vector and the constraints explicitly describe the convex hull.

Comment: It feels to me that you had to introduce quite many slack variables for that, but it might work... (Admittedly, I did not fully understand what you are about to do.)

Comment: Also related, but I cannot tell if that works: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2153051/447001

Comment: And please do not forget to post your solution when you have found one. Self-answers are welcome here.

Comment: you get a function with (n-1) parameters describing the linear combination of the n vectors with the n'th parameter being equal to 1  minus the sum of the other parameters. Then you minimize its distance to 0 constrained by all parameters and their sum being between 0 and 1. Not the most elegant solution, but it might work for small data-sets.

Comment: I see. Also, if speed matters, you might want to check first whether $0$ is contained in any quickly to compute convex bounding volume of the point set, e.g., the minimal axis-aligned bounding box. If $0$ is not contained it it, then it also cannot be contained the the covex hull.

Comment: yeah, I haven't even computed the vectors yet, still need to write some formulas. But it's on my "to do" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a "bare-bones" implementation of a function that calculates the dual cone of a given vector set. It's not fancy or efficient (plus, I'm pretty sure it goes against some code indentation rules), but it works.

```
dualCone[lis_] := Module[{l, crosLis, goodLis},
  l =  Length[lis[[1]]];
     crosLis = Apply[Join,
    Map [
     Function[subList,
      Module[{cross, val},
       cross = Apply[Cross, 4*subList];
       val = Complement[lis, subList].Normalize[cross] ;
       {{cross, Min[val]}, {-cross, Min[-val] }}]],
     Subsets[lis, {l - 1}]]
    ];
  goodLis = 
   Select[crosLis, 
    Function[x, (x[[2]] > 0) && (Norm[x[[1]]] > 0.000001)]];
  Sort[Map[Function[x, Normalize[x[[1]]]], goodLis]] 
]
```

[image: Testing the function]

The interior of a convex set includes zero if and only if the `dualCone` of that set is null. It probably doesn't work well for boundary cases, tweaking with the `(x[[2]] > 0) && (Norm[x[[1]]] > 0.000001)` constraints might help with that. Tough I'm not sure, I haven't studied the problem.

For a generic list `vec1` of vectors, the set of vectors `v` which have the property of always giving semi-pozitive dot products with the vectors of `vec1` can be generated by the [conical combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination) of the vectors given by `dualCone[vec1]`.

If the list `dualCone[vec1]` is null, no such vectors exist.

If it is not, then it contains feasible vectors, which can be used to generate all other vectors that satisfy the constraint, by conical combination.

The given definition works well for "generic" vector lists, no so much for boundary conditions.